# What happens if I catch SIGSEGV and the signal handler causes another SIGSEGV?

Tags: c, linux

This question is asked with Linux in mind. GCC compiler is used.

What behaviour can be expected if SIGSEGV (I mean a violation that normally causes SIGSEGV) occurs within a signal handler whose purpose was to catch SIGSEGV? Code example to aid the discussion:

```
/* In main or whatever */
{
  struct sigaction sa = {}; /* initialised to all zero (I vote for GCC style breach of standard here) */
  sa.sa_handler = DisasterSignals;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER;  /* To have or have not */
  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
}

static void DisasterSignals(int signal)
{
  /* We cannot save the situation, the purpose of catching the signal is
     only to do something clever to aid debugging before we go. */

  /* Q: What if we segfault in here?? */

  abort(); /* This should give us the expected core dump (if we survive to this point) */
}
```

Imagine, in the point "Q", There is an offending machine instruction.

1) Without the `SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER`: This appears to put the system in a logical trap: At "Q", SIGSEGV should be generated. But SIGSEGV is blocked in the signal handler (default sigaction behaviour). How can the execution continue? Will it freeze? Will it jump past the offending instruction (I guess not)?

2) With the `SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER`: I guess in this case the program will crash in a "normal" fashion when SIGSEGV is repeated.

3) With only `SA_NODEFER`: I guess in this case the signal handler is recursively called when SIGSEGV is repeated; if the SIGSEGV is always repeated, we get a freeze until the stack overflows, and then what.

Comment: You are supposed to only call reentrant functions in signal handlers.

Comment: What happens when an armor piercing bullet pierces armor?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40fc467ac87e9cfa My results show: 1&2 - segfault in handler crashes program instantly. 3 - signal handler recurses for about 13k times (varying) and then crashes.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html - the answer to logical trap: "       If SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV are generated while they are
       blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal was generated by
       kill(2), sigqueue(3), or raise(3)."

Comment: @black: There are no rules to stop me from attempting to write data through a pointer inside a signal handler, are there? This can segfault. (Of course there may be guidelines against this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, while signal is being handled it is masked, so it can't be triggered recursively. If masked signal is triggered by program execution (invalid memory access, segfault, division by 0 etc.), the behavior is undefined:

> If SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV are generated while they are
>          blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal was generated by
>          kill(2), sigqueue(3), or raise(3).

On my system, it causes process to crash.

With `SA_NODEFER` there is no masking, so signal can be handled recursively until stack overflows. And adding `SA_RESETHAND` would restore default action (crash for SIGSEGV).

I adapted your example to simple testing program, so you can verify this behavior:

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

volatile char *ptr;

static void DisasterSignals(int signal)
{
  /* We cannot save the situation, the purpose of catching the signal is
     only to do something clever to aid debugging before we go. */
  write(1, "11\n", 3);
  *ptr = 1;
  write(1, "13\n", 3);
  abort(); /* This should give us the expected core dump (if we survive to this point) */
}

struct sigaction sa = {}; /* initialised to all zero (I vote for GCC style breach of standard here) */

int main()
{
  sa.sa_handler = DisasterSignals;
  sa.sa_flags = /*SA_RESETHAND | */SA_NODEFER;  /* To have or have not */
  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

  write(1, "25\n", 3);
  *ptr = 1;
}
```